# Difference beween .arm and .csr file (SSL)

Tags: ssl, keytool

I am generating two CSRs ( Certificate signing request )

1 . using java keytool i get a .csr format file.

1. using IBM key management tool i get .arm file.

Though both the files contains the same kind of data ( ie . base64 encoded public key details)

My question "can i rename .csr file to .arm" will it be the same ...

Thanks.

Comment: Do they both contain the same sort of data (i.e. `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----` + base-64 of DER + `-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.  The .arm file is the same format as .csr.  As you stated, they both contain the same type of data and therefore can simply be renamed.  Furthermore, the common types of CSR requests are PKCS#10 and PKCS#12.

@snow60y: You won't see anything with 'openssl x509 -req -in yourfile.csr -text -noout' because there is no private key contained within the CSR and it is not signed, so it is not an x509 yet.  A CSR should NEVER contain a private key and therefore, analyzing with that command should fail.  You can use that command with a SIGNED cert, but not the request. For the request, use:

```
openssl req -in your-csr-filename -noout -text
```

Comment: PKCS#12 isn't a format for certificate requests, it's for storing certificates and private keys.

Answer (score 1):

The most common syntax for a CSR is [PKCS#10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986), which can be represented in binary or text formats. A CSR contains a number of pieces of information including: a public key, the subject distinguished name, a signature, and optional attributes. If you can view the files in a text editor and they look similar to this:

> ```
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
> MIIBnTCCAQYCAQAwXTELMAkGA1UEBhMCU0cxETAPBgNVBAoTCE0yQ3J5cHRvMRIw
> EAYDVQQDEwlsb2NhbGhvc3QxJzAlBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWGGFkbWluQHNlcnZlci5l
> eGFtcGxlLmRvbTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAr1nYY1Qrll1r
> uB/FqlCRrr5nvupdIN+3wF7q915tvEQoc74bnu6b8IbbGRMhzdzmvQ4SzFfVEAuM
> MuTHeybPq5th7YDrTNizKKxOBnqE2KYuX9X22A1Kh49soJJFg6kPb9MUgiZBiMlv
> tb7K3CHfgw5WagWnLl8Lb+ccvKZZl+8CAwEAAaAAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4GB
> AHpoRp5YS55CZpy+wdigQEwjL/wSluvo+WjtpvP0YoBMJu4VMKeZi405R7o8oEwi
> PdlrrliKNknFmHKIaCKTLRcU59ScA6ADEIWUzqmUzP5Cs6jrSRo3NKfg1bd09D1K
> 9rsQkRc9Urv9mRBIsredGnYECNeRaK5R1yzpOowninXC
> -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
> ```

then they are text (aka PEM) encoded CSRs. These text encoded CSRs can be decoded and viewed using the following openssl command:

```
openssl req -in your-csr-filename -noout -text
```

Renaming the file will not affect openssl's ability to decode them. However, some applications that process CSRs may expect a particular filename extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect your certificate signing request (csr) using OpenSSL with a command such as:

```
openssl x509 -req -in yourfile.csr -text -noout
```

I'm assuming that IBM's thingy is a wrapper around openssl so I would expect your .arm to be an x509 certificate going by a different name. Be interested to hear what you get back ...